# What is the best way to match vector images using OpenCV?

Tags: image, opencv, vector, pattern-matching, matching

I would like to check whether a smaller target image exists in a larger image, using OpenCV matchers: so far, it is a question asked for many times here. The problem is that my images are not photographic, but vector-based images. This seems to confuse SIFT matcher, for example, especially when there are texts in the image. When there are shapes and texts on the same target image, SIFT seems to focus more on the text because of the higher complexity. This usually results in SIFT matching the text in the target image to other texts all over the larger image.

Is there a way to configure SIFT or other matchers for better results with vector images? Or should I be looking at something completely different than OpenCV?

Comment: Your rasterized vector images are probably too sharp and different than those used during SIFT evaluation. There is a way to configure SIFT: spend some hours playing with it... Otherwise, try something else like template matching via convolution or create your own multi-signatures with many features in them (Histogram, dominant color, entropy, etc).

Comment: convert vector to raster(with same scale) and use something like chamfer matching or correlation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at specific image matching, e.g. Rath, Toni M., and Raghavan Manmatha. "Word image matching using dynamic time warping." Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition, 2003. Proceedings. 2003 IEEE Computer Society Conference on. Vol. 2. IEEE, 2003. http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.14.1326&rep=rep1&type=pdf .